# Memory exception while filtering large CSV files

Tags: powershell, csv, out-of-memory

[image]getting memory exception while running this code. Is there a way to filter one file at a time and write output and append after processing each file. Seems the below code loads everything to memory.

```
$inputFolder = "C:\Change\2019\October"
$outputFile = "C:\Change\2019\output.csv"
Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -File -Filter '*.csv' |
    ForEach-Object { Import-Csv $_.FullName } |
    Where-Object { $_.machine_type -eq 'workstations' } |
    Export-Csv $outputFile -NoType
```

Comment: CSVs are just text. The ImportCSV cmdlet is useful for manipulating CSV data in PowerShell, but if all you want to do is to append one CSV onto another (assuming they're the same width) you can just read them as if they were text.

`get-content *.csv | set-content combined.csv` 

Seems like it should work. Might have to mess with line endings?

Comment: @Joe: I need to filter the combined.csv with machine_type -eq "workstation" only

Comment: your CSVs have Always same columns in the same order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be can you export and filter your files one by one and append result into your output file like this :

```
$inputFolder = "C:\Change\2019\October"
$outputFile = "C:\Change\2019\output.csv"

Remove-Item $outputFile -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -Filter "*.csv" -file | %{import-csv $_.FullName | where machine_type -eq 'workstations' | export-csv $outputFile -Append -notype }
```

Comment: thanks for this. Even Though it still throws memory error it manages to create the csv file and append the data. I have added  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue to the export-csv line as well so it can continue with processing the data.

Comment: @Enigma: An out-of-memory error is a statement-terminating error, so it's likely that data will be missing from your output CSV file.

Comment: mklement0 has right, if you have still throws error you cant use this solution

Comment: @Enigma: After the `Export-Csv` command, you can place a command that forces garbage collection to see if that gets rid of the error: `[gc]::Collect(); [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()`; also, I've found issues on GitHub relating to the issue - see my updated answer (speaking of: I still don't understand why the `switch`-based workaround doesn't work for you).

Answer (score 1):

Note: The reason for *not* using `Get-ChildItem ... | Import-Csv ...` - i.e., for *not* directly piping `Get-ChildItem` to `Import-Csv` and instead having to call `Import-Csv` from the script block (`{ ... }` of an auxiliary `ForEach-Object` call, is a *bug* in *Windows PowerShell* that has since been fixed in PowerShell *Core* - see the bottom section for a more concise workaround.

However, even output from `ForEach-Object` script blocks should *stream* to the remaining pipeline commands, so you *shouldn't* run out of memory - after all, a salient feature of the PowerShell pipeline is *object-by-object* processing, which keeps memory use *constant*, irrespective of the size of the (streaming) input collection.

You've since confirmed that avoiding the aux. `ForEach-Object` call does *not* solve the problem, so we still don't know what causes your out-of-memory exception.

*Update*:

- [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7603) contains clues as to the reason for excessive memory use, especially with many properties that contain small amounts of data.
- [This GitHub feature request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8862) proposes using *strongly typed* output objects to help the issue.

The following **workaround**, which **uses the `switch` statement** to **process the files as *text* files**, *may* help:

```
$header = ''
Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -Filter *.csv | ForEach-Object {
  $i = 0
  switch -Wildcard -File $_.FullName {
    '*workstations*' {
      # NOTE: If no other columns contain the word `workstations`, you can 
      # simplify and speed up the command by omitting the `ConvertFrom-Csv` call 
      # (you can make the wildcard matching more robust with something 
      # like '*,workstations,*')
      if ((ConvertFrom-Csv "$header`n$_").machine_type -ne 'workstations') { continue }
      $_ # row whose 'machine_type' column value equals 'workstations'
    }
    default {
      if ($i++ -eq 0) {
        if ($header) { continue } # header already written
        else { $header = $_; $_ } # header row of 1st file
      }
    }
  }
} | Set-Content $outputFile
```

---

Here's a **workaround for the bug of not being able to pipe `Get-ChildItem` output *directly* to `Import-Csv`**, by passing it as an *argument* instead:

```
Import-Csv -LiteralPath (Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -File -Filter *.csv) |
    Where-Object { $_.machine_type -eq 'workstations' } |
    Export-Csv $outputFile -NoType
```

Note that in PowerShell *Core* you could more naturally write:

```
Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -File -Filter *.csv | Import-Csv |
  Where-Object { $_.machine_type -eq 'workstations' } |
    Export-Csv $outputFile -NoType
```

Comment: much appreciate your help with this.But im still getting memory exceptopn.`PS C:\change\2019\October> $inputFolder = "C:\Change\2019\October"
PS C:\change\2019\October> $outputFile = "C:\Change\2019\output.csv"
PS C:\change\2019\October> Import-Csv -LiteralPath (Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -File -Filter *.csv) |
>>     Where-Object { $_.machine_type -eq 'workstation' } |
>>     Export-Csv $outputFile -NoType
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
At line:1 char:1, OutOfMemoryException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.OutOfMemoryException`

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.771
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.771
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

Comment: @Enigma: Please see my update that shows another workaround. If that doesn't help, we could try forcing periodic garbage collection to force previously allocated objects to be released.

Comment: @Enigma: If no other columns contain the word `workstations`, you can simplify and speed up the command by omitting the `ConvertFrom-Csv` call (you can make the wildcard matching more robust with something like `'*,workstations,*'`)

Comment: The workaround works but the output csv seems not truncating after each line with data populating after the table header data column horizontally.

Comment: @Enigma: By _truncating_, do you mean newlines (line breaks)? The workaround sends the lines one by one to `Set-Content`, which automatically puts a newline between them. Is there something unusual about your input `*.csv` files?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2 :

```
$inputFolder = "C:\Change\2019\October"
$outputFile = "C:\Change\2019\output.csv"
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8  # modify encoding if necessary
$Delimiter=','

#find header for your files => i take first row of first file with data
$Header = Get-ChildItem -Path $inputFolder -Filter *.csv | Where length -gt 0 | select -First 1 | Get-Content -TotalCount 1

#if not header founded then not file with sise >0 => we quit
if(! $Header) {return}

#create array for header
$HeaderArray=$Header -split $Delimiter -replace '"', ''

#open output file
$w = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($outputfile, $true, $encoding)

#write header founded
$w.WriteLine($Header)


#loop on file csv
Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -File -Filter "*.csv" | %{

    #open file for read
    $r = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($_.fullname, $encoding)
    $skiprow = $true

    while ($line = $r.ReadLine()) 
    {
        #exclude header
        if ($skiprow) 
        {
            $skiprow = $false
            continue
        }

        #Get objet for current row with header founded
        $Object=$line | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $HeaderArray -Delimiter $Delimiter

        #write in output file for your condition asked
        if ($Object.machine_type -eq 'workstations') { $w.WriteLine($line) }

    }

    $r.Close()
    $r.Dispose()

}

$w.close()
$w.Dispose()
```

Comment: have you try my second proposition?

Answer (score -1):

You have to read and write to the .csv files one row at a time, using `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`:

```
$filepath = "C:\Change\2019\October"
$outputfile = "C:\Change\2019\output.csv"
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Filter *.csv | 
         Where-Object { $_.machine_type -eq 'workstations' }

$w = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($outputfile, $true, $encoding)

$skiprow = $false
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $r = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($file.fullname, $encoding)
    while (($line = $r.ReadLine()) -ne $null) 
    {
        if (!$skiprow)
        {
            $w.WriteLine($line)
        }
        $skiprow = $false
    }
    $r.Close()
    $r.Dispose()
    $skiprow = $true
}

$w.close()
$w.Dispose()
```

Comment: are we missing  Import-csv in the line...'$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Filter *.csv | 
         Where-Object { $_.machine_type -eq 'workstations' }'

Answer (score -2):

`get-content *.csv | add-content combined.csv`

Make sure combined.csv doesn't exist when you run this, or it's going to go full Ouroboros.

Comment: This will duplicate header rows in the output file, and it also doesn't address the filter requirement. (Aside from that, `Set-Content` should be used).

Comment: Won't `Set-Content` overwrite the already-set contents of `combined.csv`, leaving it a duplicate of the last CSV file that was picked up?

Comment: No, whatever Set-Content receives via the pipeline all goes into the target file.